# Reference record in pymysql to search for it

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

Is there a simple way in which I can reference a record in pymysql to see whether it exists in a table in a particular database? I want to search for a particular record and then, if it exists, reference the rest of the attributes that exist in that particular row/ tuple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
I am a beginner
Thanks

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you mean by "reference"? Are you just asking how you can query a record by id in SQL?

Comment: Sorry about that. And yes I am

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Python question.

To get all columns for a row given its primary key, you just use `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=1;
```

asssuming that the primary key column is called `id`.